# Gulp passing folder watch as parameter

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch

I have this structure:

```
- sectionA
- src
-- main1.js
-- main2.js
sectionB
- src
-- main1.js
-- main2.js
```

and I have a gulp task that look and watch for src/*.js

Is there a way to make it look for specific folder passing the folder name as parameter in terminal?

Like this:

```
gulp watch sectionA
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to make two different gulp task in case there are limited amount of section.
and run it like: 
1) gulp watchSectionA (which will watch section A js files)
2) gulp watchSectionB(which will watch section b js files)

and in case you want it to solve it by arguments there's yargs which can be used to get command line argument and than you can go and use it in src of your gulp:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/yargs